# Keystone.js Number fieldtype tweak

Tags: mongoose, keystonejs

I'm trying to add an id-like column to my keystone `events` model.
I have the following

```
// models/Event.js
var keystone = require('keystone'),
  Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Event = new keystone.List('Event');

Event.add({
  FB_event_id:    { type: Types.Number, required: true, initial: true },
  name:           { type: Types.Text },
  FB_event_name:  { type: Types.Text },
  description:    { type: Types.Textarea },
  start_time:     { type: Types.Datetime },
  end_time:       { type: Types.Datetime },
  is_date_only:   { type: Types.Boolean },
  location:       { type: Types.Text },
  owner_name:     { type: Types.Text },
  updated_time:   { type: Types.Datetime },
  venue_name:     { type: Types.Text }, // typically given if lat/long data isn't
  venue_city :    { type: Types.Text },
  venue_lat :     { type: Types.Number },
  venue_long :    { type: Types.Number },
  venue_state :   { type: Types.Text },
  venue_street :  { type: Types.Text },
  venue_zip :     { type: Types.Number },
  cover_photo:    { type: Types.S3File }
});

Event.register();
```

In the admin UI though I see `270,385,519,824,039` for `FB_event_id` which is more of a quantity number rather than an identification number. How can I remove these commas? Use a different FieldType?
Is there anyway to access the mongoose `ObjectId` field type? http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html That would be perfect I think.

This is purely an aesthetic issue (semantic perhaps). The id is stored without commas in the database.

http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this by specifying the `format` option, in your case you'd want to set it to `false` to disable the formatting entirely:

```
FB_event_id:    { type: Types.Number, format: false, required: true, initial: true }
```

(I've just updated the docs to specifically mention that you can set this option to `false` to disable formatting altogether)

The `ObjectId` field type isn't what you're after; these are used by the `Relationship` field type for linking to other documents in the database, and should only be used to store Mongo ObjectIDs. Any other values result in errors.

Personally though, I often use the `String` field for ID-type fields, it's just as effective as the `Number` field and reduces the possibility of unexpected behaviour related to parsing numbers in Javascript.